# Offchain voting

Tags: tokens, erc-20, voting

Are there any voting based approaches where voting would happen off chain, via signed messages, but then the result could be indepedently verified or even stored on chain?

- Voting rights are based on a snapshot of token (certain block)
- Votes are cast offchain, via signed messages or similar
- The voting records can be independently verified
- Does not need to be closed ballot - ok to disclose who voted and what